# Function that returns 1 given any positive number

Tags: functions

What would be a way to write a function that given any positive number the function would return one, but for a negative number or zero it would return zero.

Also what mental process should I go through to approach such a problem?

For example:

f(45) = 1;

f(10) = 1;

f(1) = 1;

f(0) = 0;

f(-3) = 0;

Comment: Do you mean something different from "if ($x > 0$) then return 1; else return 0"?

Comment: You can use $F(x)=\frac {x+|x|}{2x}$ but you still need to handle $x=0$ as a special case.

Comment: Perhaps it can be expressed as the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions

Comment: $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0&x\le0\\1&x>0\end{cases}$

Comment: $f_n(x) = e^{n(x - \vert x \vert)}$ converges pointwise to your function

Comment: Are you saying that the solution should *not* be a piecewise function / should *not* define a special case? That is implied, but it isn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\lfloor\frac{\text{sgn}(x)+1}{2}\rfloor$$

Comment: Very nice! I found that one step further covers the zero case
$$f(x)=\text{sgn}(\lfloor\frac{\text{sgn}(x)+1}{2}\rfloor)$$

Comment: Hmm, actually I'm wrong my idea didn't work for zero since it returns 1 in that case.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) is the definition of sgn$(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

It would be piecewise function like this 
$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n > 0$} \\
0, & \text{if $n \le 0$ }
\end{cases}$$